# Migrating SalesForce Marketing Cloud Campaign to another SalesForce account

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to know what is the best way to export Campaigns and email from one SFMC to another one. Does FTP help? or any other other method?

Comment: Are you talking about metadata, data or both?

Comment: API will give you the greatest flexibility but will also be quite development intensive.

Comment: Can you give me both scenarios which means only metadata or both. I know I have to use REST API for sure. However, what the automation studio where it can upload file or database?

Comment: If you need only metadata you can use ANT Migration Tool for it. If you need data you can use an ETL tool. For a one-time migration, I wouldn't use REST.

Comment: Hello Viasur, I was looking for salesforce marketing cloud ANT Migration I can't find any reference. I have found SalesForce Sales Cloud ANT migration. Do you have any link for it?